# I can post links in a page feed but not just a message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to a facebook page (as the page and as the admin user with each one access token) with just a parameter '`message`'.

I've the same error in php and in Graph API Explorer in both cases:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#1) An unknown error occurred",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "error_data": {
      "kError": 1455002
    }
  }
}
```

The same post to the API adding a paremeter `link` or just `link` without `message` works fine.

The user has granted those permissions: `create_note, email, manage_pages, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, share_item, status_update, user_friends, video_upload`.

The app is in Sandbox Mode and the user is a test user, not a real one.

I'm able to write to user feed and to create custom actions for him.

I've verified both, the page access token and the user access token with Access Token Debugger.

I've already reviewed a lot of questions in stackoverflow, tutorials and blog posts.

What am I missing?

UPDATED: I can't either post a link in page with app access token.

Comment: Can you show the exact code that you've used to post.

Comment: As I said I've the same error with Graph API Explorer so it's not related with the php code.